# Restkit serializing sub-object array as a string when attaching image

Tags: objective-c, ios, serialization, restkit

When using Restkit to send an object back to the server, I'm having a problem with a nested array of sub objects ONLY when I attach an image.

This is the mapping summary I'm using for all requests:

```
// mapping for post tag details
tagMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[TagObject class]];
[tagMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"tagId"];
[tagMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"tagName"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:tagMapping forKeyPath:@"tags"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[tagMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[TagObject class]];

// mapping for posts
poastMapping = [[RKObjectMapping alloc] init];
poastMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PoastObject class]];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"poastId"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"user_id" toAttribute:@"userId"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"blurb" toAttribute:@"blurb"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"photo" toAttribute:@"photo"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"avatar" toAttribute:@"avatar"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"date_created" toAttribute:@"dateCreated"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"firstname" toAttribute:@"firstName"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"lastname" toAttribute:@"lastName"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"session" toAttribute:@"session"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"device" toAttribute:@"device"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"comments" toAttribute:@"iComments"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"commentcount" toAttribute:@"commentCount"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"pointcount" toAttribute:@"pointCount"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"heartcount" toAttribute:@"heartCount"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"postcount" toAttribute:@"postCount"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"hearted" toAttribute:@"hearted"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"total" toAttribute:@"total"];
[poastMapping mapKeyPath:@"tags" toRelationship:@"tags" withMapping:tagMapping];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:poastMapping];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:poastMapping forKeyPath:@"posts"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[poastMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[PoastObject class]];
```

And this is the block that sends the request (note that certain changes are only occurring when an image is attached)

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] sendObject:obj toResourcePath:@"/posts/submit" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.targetObject = nil;
        loader.delegate = self;
        loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;

        if([obj image]){
            RKObjectMapping* serializationMapping = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] serializationMappingForClass:[PoastObject class]];
            NSError* error = nil;
            NSDictionary* dictionary = [[RKObjectSerializer serializerWithObject:obj mapping:serializationMapping] serializedObject:&error];
            RKParams* params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:dictionary];
            NSData* imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation([obj image]);
            [params setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/png" forParam:@"image"];
            loader.params = params;
        }
    }];
```

When sending a request without the image, the 'tags' array arrives in PHP as type 'array' as expected. However, when sending a request with the image, the tags array comes in as a type 'string' and looks like the following:

> (
>           {
>           id = 2;
>           name = Science;
>       },
>           {
>           id = 4;
>           name = Academics;
>       } )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I could find around this was to simply add the nested array again as a JSON encoded string for that parameter and then json_decode on the server side. Still not sure why this bug is happening.

Updated Code:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] sendObject:obj toResourcePath:@"/posts/submit" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {

    loader.targetObject = nil;
    loader.delegate = self;
    loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;

    RKObjectMapping* serializationMapping = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] serializationMappingForClass:[PoastObject class]];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [[RKObjectSerializer serializerWithObject:obj mapping:serializationMapping] serializedObject:&error];

    // grab the tag array
    NSArray *tags = [dictionary objectForKey:@"tags"];
    NSString *tagData = [tags JSONString];

    RKParams* params = [RKParams paramsWithDictionary:dictionary];

    // assign tags as a value in the parameters manually
    [params setValue:tagData forParam:@"tags"];

    // add image if it exists
    if([obj imageV]){
        NSData* imageData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation([obj imageV], 0.75);
        [params setData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/jpg" forParam:@"image"];
    }

    loader.params = params;

}];
```